# How to generate right-direction arrow using PlantUML new Activity Diagram syntax?

Tags: uml, plantuml

How can I create right-directed arrow in the PlantUML new Activity Diagram syntax?

Using the old syntax, I can use `-right->`, but I don't find any similar notation from the [new syntax guide](http://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta). How can you achieve the same result with the new syntax? I need to use the new syntax because of its Swimlane support.

Example of diagram with right arrow using old syntax:

```
@startuml
(*) --> "An Activity"
-right->  "Another Activity"
--> (*)
@enduml
```

[image: Diagram generated using above code]

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know this is still not possible, and I haven't seen it in incubation either ( http://plantuml.com/incubation ).

Answer (score 4):

In theory based on the [documentation](http://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta) of PlantUML and [its source code](https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/blob/master/src/net/sourceforge/plantuml/activitydiagram/command/CommandLinkActivity.java#L88-L92) this should work:

```
@startuml
start
:An Activity;
-right->
:Another Activity;
stop
@enduml
```

But I try it in the online editor of it and the result is different:
http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuG8pkAmSynGSaqioop9BAgsvT8ioqpDATEr0mlab6Qb523cW-lm2BeVKl1IWPW00

Because other formatting can be used (e.g. [blue, dashed arrow](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuG8pkAmSynGSaqioop9BAgsvTAELat9AKtLI4eipKbDYTUr0ylab6Qb524L0ZVa5N0wfUIb0Km00)) I don't understand why this is not working. Maybe this should be reported as a bug to the developers of PlantUML.

Answer (score -4):

```
@startuml
(*) --> "An Activity"
->  "Another Activity"
--> (*)
@enduml
```

Worked for me. 
`->` is for right, `-->` is for down.

This does seem to only work when activities are named with quotation marks. 
When they are named with `:x;` syntax, this does not work

Comment: This is the old syntax, not the new as OP asked for. `->` is simply a shorter line than `-->` and not for right/down as you claim.